# PHP extensions missing error

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using Godaddy hosting and I have selected the PHP 5.4 version, everything was running fine but suddenly my sub-domains stopped working and on new installation it shows the followings errors:
1) Mcrypt PHP extension missing!
2) Mysqli PHP extension missing!
3) MBString PHP extension missing!
4) GD PHP extension missing!

all these extensions are enabled Godaddy PHP settings:

[image]

please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your required php ext didn't enable :|, I have checked it in list :) enable all of theme and restart apache :)

[image]

Comment: I have enabled all of them but same issue :(

Comment: Have you restart apache service ??

Comment: GoDaddy doesn't allow to restart apache on web hosting

Comment: Just request system admin or I think GoDaddy have noti you your change will effect after some minute :) .. jush find noty and waiting :)

Comment: when i changed my PHP version 5.4(native) then change will effect in seconds but when i selected version 5.4 or another it will not take any effect. i have already tried this also.

Comment: I have research and found this :).. I hope it help: https://vn.godaddy.com/help/enabling-apache-or-php-modules-using-easyapache-6237